# controller not sending data codeignitter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a ready ci application and I am trying to use ajax but even I tried many correct codes the get works but the post never I think there is some problem with config
ajax_test view

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var base_url = "<?=base_url()?>";
   $(document).ready (function(){
    $('#get_bt').click(function(){
        $.post(base_url+'ajax_test/info_page' , {name:'bashir' , id:'1'}, function(data){
            alert(data);

        })
        });
});
```

```
<button id="get_bt">get</button>
```

controller

```
<?php
 class Ajax_test extends CI_Controller {
 public function index(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view("ajax_test");

}
public function info_page(){
    echo $this->input->post('name');
}
}   
?>
```

Note it works with get instead of post 
The jquery error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: check your url, because its working fine on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 403 error is because of a configuration setting. In the file */application/config/config.php* you have the following setting.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

Which is a good thing but also requires that you send the CSRF token name/value to the controller along with the 'name' and 'id'.

Check out the documentation on [Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#id2) to learn how to get those values.

Or you can use GET as another answer suggested. (GET doesn't check CSRF.)

Or you can use `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` (Generally a bad idea.)

Or you can whitelist the URI using the following in */application/config/config.php*

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('ajax_test/info_page');
```

But sending the CSRF credentials is the most secure and therefore best solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
$name = $_GET['name'];

echo $name
```

instead of using input->post

or change your ajax to

```
$.ajax({
        url: your url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {name:"bashir"},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success")
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```